# Race/Gender inquire when applying to an Equal Opportunity Employment company

Tags: united-states, applications, equality

Companies in the US mention being an Equal Opportunity Employer. Employment decisions are made without regard to race, color, religion, sex, sexual orientation, gender identity.

But why do they ask if the applicant is white, black, latino, has aids or with disabilities?

Comment: Probably they just want your info into their databases. Also, may be that application forms still ask for those "legacy" questions.

Comment: I edited your questionand gave it a more meaningful title, plus some additional tags so you get better help. Feel free to further edit it to improve its quality and possibly add more detail to your problem.

Comment: Isn't responding to those questionnaires optional?

Comment: Did you equate "religion, sex, sexual orientation, and gender identity" with AIDS??? Seriously? Are you trolling us? Who asked you if you had AIDS?

Answer (score 4):

That is separate tracking and is not meant to be part of the employment decision.  Usually (always?) that part of the questionnaire does not go to the hiring manager with the resume and the rest of the application.

But in order to know if the concept of equal opportunity is working, they need to track what kind of people are applying and being hired.  That information goes to the government, which can track trends in hiring.

Comment: True, how can you tell if you are being equal if you don't know what people work for you? Some companies even require a minimum % of employees to be of a minority group, so they *have* to track that percentage closely.

Comment: Well it could be asked right after having a signed contract also, but indeed some information about the applicants self might be useful for statistics. Like "we have 10% of european people, but they also only represent 10% of applicants. And anyway any face to face interview would provide some of these informations.

Comment: As well as not going to the hiring manager, application forms almost always indicate that giving the information is entirely voluntary.

Comment: @GrayCygnus:  I'll turn your question around.  How can you tell if you are being equal if you DO know what people work for you?  For example, if your workforce diversity exactly matches your area's demographic, that would be strong evidence that you worked hard to achieve that result instead of striving to make sure that "Employment decisions are made without regard to...".

Answer (score -2):

"But why do they ask if the applicant is white, black, latino, has aids or with disabilities?"

Do they? Any HR person asking such questions would be deemed incompetent, because if you are not hired, then you have an obvious indication for discrimination. Which of course may never have happened, but it opens them up for a lawsuit.

Now I would want to know if you have ever heard of anyone outside the adult entertainment industry having been asked if they have AIDS. I can promise you that if I was asked that question by HR, I would do whatever is in my power to remove the person asking the question from the company, and if I didn't succeed, to cause maximum negative publicity to the company. I am surely not alone in this, so I am quite sure that absolutely nobody would ask that question twice.